# Shell: parallel command to execute as user postgres via root

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, shell, quoting

I use this `parallel` call to do something as user `postgres` via passwordless ssh access of user `root`:

```
parallel -q -j0 ssh {} -l root "sudo -u postgres  -i psql -tAc 
    \"select current_user, current_database()\" -d \$(echo {}| cut -d@ -f1) "
     ::: db_foo@host1 db_bar@host2 ...
```

... it works except for hosts running older linux systems.

I get this message from old system:

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "current_database()" ignored
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "current_user,"
```

Versions:

- GNU bash, Version 4.1.10(1)
- Sudo version 1.7.6p2

How to get the quoting right to get this working on old linux systems?

## Update

With the quoting from the answer of Paul A Jungwirth, this result happens:

```
===> parallel -q -j0 ssh {} -l root "echo \$BASH_VERSION; rpm -qf /usr/bin/sudo; sudo -u postgres  -i psql -tAc '\"select current_user, current_database()\"' -d \$(echo {}| cut -d@ -f1); echo " ::: ...

4.2.53(1)-release
sudo-1.8.6p3-3.13.1.x86_64

ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""select current_user, current_database()""
ZEILE 1: "select current_user, current_database()"
         ^
4.1.10(1)-release
sudo-1.7.6p2-0.16.1.x86_64

psql: warning: extra command-line argument "current_database()"" ignored
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "current_user,"
```

.... I guess I will give up and use two loops. The first to scp a script, the second to call this script.

Comment: Looks like a postgres error, not a bash or sudo error.

Comment: Trying to pass multiple levels of quoting through an ssh connection invariably leads to sadness, and combining that with `parallel` is just going to make things worse.  Consider putting your command into a script instead so that you can avoid needing to muck about with quotes on the command line.

Comment: If you have root access to the box, I would recommend configuring `sudo` to allow a regular user to run the desired `psql` command without a password, rather than logging in as root just to avoid typing a password for the `sudo` command.

Comment: Or better yet, configure the PostGres database to accept remote connections: `parallel -q -j0 psql -h {} '...'`.

Comment: @chepner yes, configuring postgres to accept remote connections could help. But then I would need to care about passwordless logins. That's why I prefer to use ssh via root.

Comment: @glennjackman you think this is a psql issue? I don't think so. The word "current_database()" is SQL. But on old linux systems psql gets this as paramter (outside -c "..."). That's why I think that the quoting gets done in a different way on old systems.

Comment: On the hosts that fail, what shell (name and version) is used? The version of `sshd` might also be relevant.

Comment: @chepner the shell and sudo versions are in the question. Unfortunately I can't get the ssh/sshd version at my current workplace.

Comment: Why are you connecting as `root` and running `sudo` instead of simply connecting as the user `postgres`?

Comment: @eradman I connect as root, since this works without a password.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it:

```
parallel -q -j0 ssh {} -l root "sudo -u postgres  -i psql -tAc 
    '\"select current_user, current_database()\"' -d \$(echo {}| cut -d@ -f1) "
     ::: db_foo@host1 db_bar@host2 ...
```

With your original version, the inner double-quotes are interpreted when you call sudo, so that sudo gets these arguments:

```
1: -u
2: postgres
3: -i
4: psql
5: -tAc
6: select current_user, current_database()
```

In more recent versions of sudo, it will automatically escape non-alphanumeric characters in "command" arguments to keep things together, but you need to do that yourself for older versions. So newer versions will basically run this:

```
psql -tAc select\ current_user\,\ current_database\(\)
```

But older versions aren't that helpful. For those, you want to make sure that when sudo runs its command, the query is still one big argument to `psql`. By wrapping it in single quotes, you can make sure that sudo gets this:

```
1: -u
2: postgres
3: -i
4: psql
5: -tAc
6: "select current_user, current_database()"
```

So then it will run

```
psql -tAc "select current_user, current_database()"
```

rather than

```
psql -tAc select current_user, current_database()
```

Btw I found [this commit to sudo](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/rev/d35a3f4cb3c0) that seems related (from 2010), although in theory it should be part of 1.7.6 ([tagged in 2011](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/rev/fafbb7b0aea2)). Maybe there was another change later.

Unfortunately I think this new version will now break *recent* versions of sudo! Sorry about that..... I'm not sure yet how to write one command that works on both.

Edit: Btw just for fun a wrote a [little utility](https://github.com/pjungwir/argv) to help see what each command is receiving as its arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much for you trying to find a solution. I updated the question. It still does not work. .... I guess I will give up and use two loops. The first to scp a script, the second to call this script.

Comment: If doing things in two steps bothers you, you could also (1) use `su` instead of `sudo`, since you are starting as the root user, or (2) put this into a *local* script: `sudo -u postgres -i psql -tAc "select current_user, current_database()" -d $hostname` and then run `cat do-psql.sh | parallel -q -j0 ssh {} -l root "env hostname=\$(echo {} | cut -d@ f1) sh" ::: ....`. Personally I would do (1).